# Obtain the best response dynamics

Tags: game-theory

If we define a Nash equilibrium as a fixed point of the best-response mapping, i.e. a strategy $x$ s.t.
$$x\in BR(x),$$
where BR denotes the (set-valued) best-response mapping, then
$$\dot x \in BR(x)-x$$
is generally referred to as best-response dynamics (BR dynamics).

I would like toho obtain the BR dynamics for the following game. I have two utility functions, $u_1(c,s)$ and $u_2(c,s)$. They are derivable. $u_1(c,s)$ refers to Player 1, while $u_2(c,s)$ to Player 2. The strategic leverage of Player 1 is $s$ while the strategic leverage of Player 2 is $c$.

In order to obtain the best response functions and Nash equilibria, I have to solve the system of the following two equations:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial s}u_1(c,s)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial c}u_2(c,s)=0$$
From this I obtain both best response functions, i.e.
$$s=f_1(c)$$
$$c=f_1(s)$$
What is the BR dynamics for this game? Moreover, when can I substitute $\in$ symbol with $=$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the best response functions are $s = f_1(c)$ and $c = f_2(s)$. Then, let $x = (s,c)$  and the best response dynamics are,
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &\in BR(x) - x \\
\begin{pmatrix}\dot{s} \\ \dot{c}\end{pmatrix} &\in \begin{pmatrix} f_1(c) \\ f_2(s)\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} s \\ c\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

You can only replace the $\in$ with $=$ if the map $f_1, f_2$ are not set value maps but are single-valued, i.e., there is only 1 best action player 1 can take against player 2's action. For example, if $s$ is restricted between 0 and 1, the utility function for player 1 is $cs$ and $c=0$ then any $s\in(0,1)$ is the best response and therefore isn't single-valued.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clear. But I have a doubt. If I uderstand the definition of set-valued function (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function) I think that $cs$ is not one of these functions because we have many values of domain that are associated to only one value of codomain (and not viceversa)

Comment: The best response for player 1 is the action $s$ that maximizes the utility function $u_1(c,s)$ given $c$. So the domain is the actions of player 2 and the codomain are the actions of player 1 for the best response map of player 1. So given that player 2 selects $c = 0$ then all actions give equal maximum utility. There is not a single action $s$ that gives the maximum utility, f_1(c=0) = (0,1).